# Connected components of k-CNF formulas

Tags: ds.algorithms, sat

Let $F$ be a random k-CNF formula with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses. Let $G$ be the undirected graph built in the following manner: there is a vertex $v$ for every clause $c \in F$, and there is an edge $e = (v, u)$ if and only if the clause corresponding to $v$ has at least one variable in common with the clause corresponding to $u$.

The question is: how many variables, on average, shall I remove from $F$ before $G$ gets divided into 2 or more connected components? Is such number of variables related to $r = \frac{m}{n}$?

Here is what I mean by "removing  a variable $v$ from a formula $F$": every clause $c$ in which $v$ is mentioned (no matter if positive or negative) gets shortened; if $c$ becomes empty, then it is removed from $F$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll reword the question. Jukka, did you see the last answer to my question "Monotone-2SAT and Vertex Cover"?

Comment: $G'$ does not seem to add anything to your setup, as it is simply a forest of cliques.  You seem to be asking about the average connectivity of $G$, but what is the distribution of functions?

Comment: I think you're right in saying that $G'$ doesn't add any value. Maybe I'll remove it from the question. Concerning your question, I forgot to say that the k-CNF formulas are random.

Comment: Are the k-CNF formulas chosen uniformly at random from among the ones with m clauses and n variables?

Comment: @Andras: Yes, they are.

Comment: 1. As András commented, the minimum number of vertices you have to remove to make a graph disconnected plus 1 is called the [(vertex) connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph) of the graph.  If this is what you are interested in, adding this term may help reader to understand the question better.  2. You may want to add a reformulated version of the question without referring to CNF formulas because the negation does not play any role in the question.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: $G$'s vertices correspond to $F$'s clauses: if I remove a vertex from $G$ it means I'm removing a clause from $F$. But I'm interested in removing variables of $F$, not clauses. Anyhow I feel that what Andras said is in some way related to what I'm asking. In other words: given a formula $F$, how many variables shall I remove (and which ones) in order that $F$ gets divided into 2 or more disjoint sub-formulas? Here "disjoint" means that the sub-formulas do not share any variable. @Andras: I don't see your comment any longer.

Comment: Oops, you are right.  The item 1 in my previous comment was wrong.  I realized that I did not understand the problem; what do you mean by removing a variable from a CNF formula?  More specifically, if you remove a variable, do the clauses containing that variable disappear, or do they still exist (with one less alternatives)?  Does it depend on whether the variable is negated in the clause or not?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Let me be more precise than I previously were. If I remove a variable, the clauses containing that variable do not disappear (except in case of unit clauses): they still exist with one less alternative. It does not depend on whether the variable is negated in the clause or not: e.g. if we have clause $c = l_1 \lor \lnot l_2 \lor l_3$ and we remove variable $v_2$, such clause becomes $c = l_1 \lor l_3$.

Comment: In my opinion you should state the definition of “removing a variable” in the question because it is far from obvious.  In particular, your previous comment implies that a unit clause disappears if the only variable in it is removed; this is counter-intuitive (almost contradictory) when compared to the other case, and has to be stated explicitly if that is really what you want.  (more)

Comment: (Cont’d)  Also, I do not see any role played by the negation, and moreover I find the question stated in terms of CNF formula rather confusing because the definition of “removing a variable” does not seem to be any meaningful operation on CNF formulas such as assigning a value to a variable.  The question seems to be about a set system (or equivalently a hypergraph).

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: OK, I've improved the question. You're right in saying that the negation doesn't play any relevant role.

Comment: Based on the comments, is this a correct reformulation? "Given a hypergraph chosen uniformly at random from among those with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, what is the expected vertex connectivity of its Gaifman graph?"

Comment: @Andras - I think it should be "Given a k-uniform hypergraph..."

Comment: Also, I think it can be said that a hypergraph is connected if and only if its Gaifman graph is connected. So in that case what we are really asking is to find the average vertex connectivity of a k-uniform hypergraph. So we can as well start with the case when k = 2, that is, a graph. Does anyone know what's the average vertex connectivity of a graph?

Comment: According to this post - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28299/vertex-connectivity-of-random-graphs - on MO, the expected vertex connectivity of an Erdos-Renyi G(n, p) is pn as n approaches infinity. I think the analysis can be extended to the case of k-uniform hypergraphs too.

Comment: @András: Nice reformulation!  Just to make sure, are you taking variables as vertices of the hypergraph?  In that case, according to the definition in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph#Terminology), we are speaking of the Gaifman graph of the _dual_ of this hypergraph, because there the Gaifman graph is defined as a synonym of the primal graph.

Comment: There are so many comments that it might be a good idea to (1) close this question, and (2) create a new question that re-states it in terms of the average connectivity of random (hyper)graphs, with a link to this thread.

Comment: @Walter: @Jukka's point is a good one, this "thread" is becoming hard to follow without threading.

Comment: Closed at request of original poster.