# Graph Connectivity

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-algorithms

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, I need to determine:

1. $k$, the graph connectivity.
2. Which are those $k$ vertices to remove to make $G$ disconnected.

> **Questions**
>
> - Which is the complexity of such problem?
> - Which are the fastest algorithms known?
> - What about if, additionally, I require that the resulting connected components have almost the same number of edges?

This question is an improvement of [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/connected-components-of-k-cnf-formulas) question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both can be done efficiently.  You can compute the connectivity of a graph by testing the connectivity of every pair using max-flow/min-cut and taking the smallest of the values gives you $k$ (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29#Computational_aspects) on Menger's theorem) -- this gives you (1).  Using the procedure above, you can test each vertex, one at a time, to see if its removal will decrease the connectivity. Once you find such a vertex, remove it and proceed -- this gives you (2).

Comment: I doubt this is the fastest though.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut gives references to faster algorithms.

Comment: I'm sure it's not the fastest...

Comment: For fast algorithms look at the paper of Henzinger, Rao and Gabow. dx.doi.org/10.1006/jagm.1999.1055

Answer (score 5):

> What about if, additionally, I require that the resulting connected components have almost the same number of edges?

Then you are [in trouble](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node95.html).

This is not exactly the same problem, but in general the following seems to hold for many variants of the theme: it is easy to find small cuts, but hard to find small balanced cuts (for any reasonable definitions of "small" and "balanced").